# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() - On call function more one times

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem on call this function more one times

**Index.php**

```
<?php
function check_status($id){
require_once ('inc/connect.php');
try {

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT `usage` FROM `room` WHERE `id` = :id');
$query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$row = $query ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}catch (PDOException $e) {
   exit($e->getMessage());
}

if($row[0]>0) {
$msg = 'Room: Closed'; }
else {
$msg = 'Room: Opened'; }

echo $msg;

 $db = null; 
}
?>
<body>
        <?php echo check_status("1"); ?>
        <?php echo check_status("2"); ?>
</body>
```

**Connect.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = ('localhost');
$dbname = ('db_name');
$dbuser = ('user_name');
$dbpass = ('test');
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
?>
```

The first call works fine, but the second, say this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/public_html/index.php on line 6
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: is your database connecting correctly??

Comment: Yes, the first call to the function works fine, but the second no

Comment: `var_dump($db);` and see that it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Your function is horrible: you shouldn't connect to the database every time you run a query. It will consume a lot of resources. Please, make a global $db variable and reuse it everywhere:

```
require_once ('inc/connect.php');
function check_status($id){
    global $db;
    try {
    ...
    }

    //remove $db = null;
}
```

Comment: Please stop giving terrible advices. Hint: all the data available in a function should come through arguments

Comment: @zerkms "all the data available in a function should come through arguments" - absolutely not

Comment: pls remember, for php-fpm, one request, one process, if the request finished, all resources will be released. In your case, it's also one request one connection, no much difference.

Comment: @TroyCheng: it's truth not only for php-fpm, but for all SAPIs

Comment: @TroyCheng Excuse me, do you mean, that after 1 SQL request PDO disconnects from the database? I definitely know, it's not true. Maybe, I don't understand you?

Comment: @user4035: you're confusing "request" and "query" terms. They are not interchangeable

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, I thought, it's the same thing: sending SQL to the database, executing it and fetching the result (if needed). What's the difference?

Comment: Here 'PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT' has not been set, for a short connection, it should be released after the request finished.

Comment: @user4035. In one request, you may have multiple DB queries. I mean this 'request' finished, RSHUTDOWN and MSHUTDOWN level will release all resources.

Comment: @TroyCheng Ok, I'll try to run this script on my machine and publish the code, that works.

Comment: @TroyCheng Ok, my code works. Using include_once inside the function gives these 2 errors: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db in /home/user/work/stackoverflow/PDO/script.php on line 7
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/user/work/stackoverflow/PDO/script.php on line 7
I don't know, how it worked for the PO once.

Comment: @TroyCheng Anybody can reproduce my working script, taking the code here: http://pastebin.com/RtRUMA5C

Comment: It seems whole discussion is spawned by wrong choice of wording. Make it "query" and noone will be able to nitpick on it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you, sir. But interesting, why did the PO say, that "The first call works fine" - I reproduced his code, and nothing worked.

Comment: Yes, it's a mystery. I've no idea, though, HOW one can manage to get such an error. But PHP users are so ingenious in this area... Additional error reporting may help.

Comment: @user4035 I know your code works. OK, now it's clear what we discussed is not on one point. For PO's 'execute once', I do not know either. If the connection released somewhere and used again, it may cause what he said 'execute once'.